# How to convert array of arrays to associated array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table in my database for storing settings. It contains columns of 'id', 'name' and 'value'. I need to select all of them and use the keys to get the values simply.

```
SELECT * FROM settings
```

The result is:

```
array( array(id1, name1, value1), array(id2, name2, value2), ... )
```

I need call the values simply, like:

```
$value1 = $settings['name1'];
```

So I should convert the result array to this:

```
array( name1 => value1, name2 => value2, ... )
```

How can I do this using PHP ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with a cascade of built-in functions, for example:

```
$a = array( array("key1" => "value1"), array("key2" => "value2"), array("key3" => "value3"));

$b = array_combine(
    array_map('key', $a),
    array_map('end', $a));
```

or

```
$b = array_reduce($a, function($x, $y) { return $x + $y; }, $a[0]);
```

However, loops in php are usually cleaner, easier to understand and more efficient:

```
$b = array();
foreach($a as $item)
    $b += $item;
```

There's no sound reason to avoid loops.

UPD, as per your update

```
$a = array( array('id1', 'name1', 'value1'), array('id2', 'name2', 'value2'));

$b = array_combine(
    array_column($a, 1),
    array_column($a, 2));
```

returns `[name1] => value1, [name2] => value2`

If your php doesn't support `array_column`, you can include the [shim](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column), or just use a loop, which, once again, turns out to be simpler and more readable:

```
foreach($a as $x)
    $result[ $x[1] ] = $x[2];
```

Comment: I agree it's a bad idea to 'avoid' features; however, there *are* sound reasons why loops are often a poor choice. They're not composable, eg. we can't do `foreach (foreach $x as $y {} as $z) {}`, but we can easily do `array_map($f, array_map($g, $x))` or (more efficient) `array_map(compose($f, $g), $x)`. They don't allow abstraction, eg. we can do `f($x, 'array_map')` but we can't do `f($x, 'for')`. Your 'cleaner, easier to understand and more efficient' example is actually an ugly, complex, slow version of `$c = array_sum($a)`.

Comment: @georg Ah yes, my mistake. I saw the "+=" and assumed it was calculating a numeric total, not a merged-together array.

Comment: Sorry, but the array_column is not defined at my web server.

Comment: Is there any other way? my server is PHP v5.3.28

Comment: @JohnSmith: just use a loop: `foreach($a as $x) $result[$x[1]]=$x[2];`

Comment: I used loop instead. But if you found any other way, please update the topic. Thanks

Comment: These are all nice but they require making a copy.. I have posted what I believe to be a more efficient solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just through i would offer this as well. This will allow you to get what you want without ever creating the copy. You also get the efficiency of a reverse loop if this happens to be a very long array.

```
$array = array( array("key1" => "value1"), array("key2" => "value2") );

for($i = sizeof($array) - 1; $i > -1; $i--) {
    $key = array_keys($array[$i])[0];
    $value = $array[$i][$key];
    unset($array[$i]);
    $array[$key] = $value;
}

var_dump($array);
```

Or if we want everyone to be like whats going on when they read it we can do this. although you now are making two calls to array_keys which is less than optimal.

```
$array = array( array("key1" => "value1"), array("key2" => "value2") );

for($i = sizeof($array) - 1; $i > -1; $i--) {
    $array[array_keys($array[$i])[0]] = $array[$i][array_keys($array[$i])[0]];
    unset($array[$i]);
}

var_dump($array);
```

You would have to modify the indices and a few other things since the OP has changed the question from the original one as usual but with the original array posted this would work and i'm sure you could figure out how to modify it to work with the new array.